# Markup not working properly

Tags: support, markdown

As shown in the picture below, taken from this question- [What happens before the Crippled God?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2203/what-happens-before-the-crippled-god) . The `__italic__` actually bolds things instead of italicising them.

[image: Screenshot for bug]

Answer (score 4):

*Italic* uses a single underscore on each side, or a single *asterisk*. **Bold** uses two **underscores** or two asterisks.

Comment: *Italic* could also be done using single asterisk.